# Executing multiple SQL queries on Spark - Table or view not found

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

I trying to execute these spark statements but it is not working

```
spark.sql("CREATE OR REPLACE GLOBAL TEMPORARY VIEW VIEW_1 
AS SELECT * from orc.`/apps/hive/warehouse/userdb.db/rib_ies_liensserveurs`")   

spark.sql("CREATE OR REPLACE GLOBAL TEMPORARY VIEW VIEW_2 AS SELECT * from VIEW_1") 

spark.sql("SELECT * from VIEW_2").show()
```

This fails with the following error -

> Table or view not found: VIEW_1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you registering your data as `GLOBAL TEMPORARY VIEW` 
Try using Just `TEMPORARY VIEW`

global temp view to share the data through **different** sessions

Comment: If GLOBAL TEMPORARY, we must add juste global_temp.VIEW_1